# If I have a number in a shell script, how would i access just one digit of that number?

Tags: shell, numeric-data

I want to be able to go through and access each digit individually in a shell script. How would I do this?

Comment: in what format do you have the number? a parameter? in a variable? in a file? what kind of number? ("INFINITY", 5e10, -2.3, etc?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat numbers as strings, because fundamentally that is what they are*:

```
$ number=42
$ echo "${number:1:1}"
2
$ echo "${number:0:1}"
4
```

* Unless you declare the variable as an integer (for example in Bash), in which case it's **converted to a decimal number** before you can treat it as a string. For example an octal number:

```
$ declare -i number=042
$ echo "${number:0:1}"
3
$ echo "${number:1:1}"
4
```

None of this applies to decimal or floating point numbers, which *nix shells do not support directly. For that you'd want to look into `bc`.

You can also [treat a string as an array of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7578930/96588) in many different ways.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ number=12345
$ echo $number, length ${#number}
12345, length 5
$ echo ${number:0:1}
1
$ echo ${number:0:2}
12
$ echo ${number:0:3}
123
$ echo ${number:0:4}
1234
$ echo ${number:0:5}
12345
$ echo ${number:1:4}
2345
$ echo ${number:2:3}
345
$ echo ${number:3:2}
45
$ echo ${number:4:1}
5    
$ echo ${number:1}
2345
$ echo ${number:2}
345
$ echo ${number:3}
45
$ echo ${number:4}
5
$ echo ${number: -1}
5
$ echo ${number: -2}
45
$ echo ${number: -3}
345
$ echo ${number: -4}
2345
$ echo ${number:0:-4}
1
$ echo ${number:0:-3}
12
$ echo ${number:0:-2}
123
$ echo ${number:0:-1}
1234
```

All these possible combinations of `${parameter:offset:length}` can be a bit confusing...